# measure shared perimeter between image objects in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Imagine we have a image like this. Which red is the background, and we have several objects shown by different colors (and numbers over it). 
I can get labeled matrix, and use regionprops to get properties of each object like area, perimeter, etc. The question is how can I measure shared perimeter between objects and get a matrix which row and columns are object number.

[image]

For example in this case would be 8x8 matrix. Each cell of matrix will show shared perimeters between 2 objects like this:

```
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
1 50 15 20 0  0  0  0  0
2 15 40 12 0  0  0  0  0
3 ...
4
5
6 0
7
8
(1,2) = 15 %meaning that shared perimeter between object 1 and 2 is 15.
%Basically this means that (2,1) is also 15.
(1,1) = 50 %meaning that total perimeter of object 1 is 50.
(6,1) = 0
(1,7) = 0
...
```

Is there any built-in function exist in MATLAB to do it? or can anyone come up with smart solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many ways you could do this and the answer depends on how you define the number of pixels on the perimeter, inside or outside. Starting from the labeled image, limg, I would create a mask for each object, dilate it by a pixel and see how many of each other object where covered by the mask, something like:

```
for i=1:numobj
mask=zeros(size(limg));
mask(limg==i)=1;
mask=bwmorph(mask, 'dilate');
for j=1:numobj
M(i, j)=sum(mask(limg==j));
end
M(i, i)=sum(sum(edge(mask))); %This may not be consistent definitions of perimeter I haven't though about it.
```

Comment: In that case, I believe we can live with showing %. When we have total perimeter of an object (by any means), and by having % distribution of shared perimeter with other objects we can calculate perimeter.